# LotusNotes: API support for directly uploading the ID file to Vault without saving it in a file

Tags: java, lotus-notes

When we register a user using Admin console of LotusNotes with IDVault configured, it asks if we want to set the location of the ID file for the user (we can browse and set the location of the file). If we do not select the check-box, it uploads the ID file in Vault and does not create it's copy anywhere else.

But, when we do it through the Registration class (JAVA API NCSO.jar), it asks for idfilepath paramter while registering the user(registerNewUser() method).

Is there any way by which we can programatically register the user with it's ID file directly getting uploaded in Vault and we do not have to provide the path for the directory?

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is that the file path argument is still required.

Comment: Is this also your question? It sounds almost identical, even in wording: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182960/lotus-domino-9-unable-to-register-user-without-creating-id-file-using-java-clie