# Lotus Domino 9: Unable to register user without creating ID file using Java client API

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

On an ID Vault configured Domino setup, when we register a user using Admin console, his/her ID file gets uploaded to ID Vault. In addition to this Admin can also chose to create ID file on some other specified location .

That is, Admin will be able to perform registration in two ways:

Option A: Admin will only chose to create file in ID Vault.

Option B: Admin will specify path where ID file will be created in addition to ID Vault.

I am using Lotus Notes Java client API to perform registration against the same setup. The issue is that I am not able to perform registration using Option A see above).

The method we call for registration of user has a mandatory parameter for ID file path. When executed, this method will create an ID file on the specified path in addition to one uploaded in ID Vault.

I have a requirement to perform registration with Option A.

Things i have tried:

1. Sending null/blank to value to this parameter causes run-time Exception.
2. Giving only the file name creates ID file in Lotus installation directory.

Setup details:

- Lotus Domino 9
- ID Vault configured

Client API details:

- Lotus notes Java client API (NCSO.jar)

I think it's not possible to perform registration without creating file through this API.

Need some expert opinion here?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you're right. It's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `NotesRegistration`- class did not follow the development in admin- client. As for today there is no method to register a user without having an ID saved locally, as "filepath" is a mandatory parameter for `registerNewUser` method.

The only property that comes close is the `IsNoIDFile`- property, but it does not help here, as with that property set to `False` in my test no ID was generated at all (ID Vault was empty)...

Knowing that you can only "workaround" the bahaviour by deleting the created ID instantly after the method has finished.

I tried to find a PMR / SPR for that issue, as this might have probably been reported to IBM before, but I could not find one. If you need that feature, then you need to open a PMR with IBM and ask them for a "fix" for the class.